# $client->authenticate($_GET['code']) showing error while using google plus login in CodeIgniter

Tags: api, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am using CodeIgniter v3.1.4 for one of my project.In one of the page i'm trying to use Google+ login API.I have successfully created the 'client_id','client_secret' & 'redirect_uri'.I am try to follow the tutorial found at https://shareurcodes.com/blog/login%20with%20google%20codeigniter

Login page View

```
<a href="<?=site_url();?>alumni/glogin/" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google-plus">
   <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
     Login with Google
</a>
```

Inside Controller-Alumni

```
public function index($pg_name)
{
    If($pg_name == 'glogin')
    {
        $this->glogin();
    }
    elseif($pg_name == 'gcallback')
    {
        $this->gcallback();
    }
}

public function glogin()
{
    $client_id = 'SECRET CLIENT ID';
    $client_secret = 'SECRET CLIENT SECRET';
    $redirect_uri = base_url('alumni/gcallback/');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("sbcur-g-login");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");

    $objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: '.$authUrl);
}

public function gcallback()
{
    $client_id = 'SECRET CLIENT ID';
    $client_secret = 'SECRET CLIENT SECRET';
    $redirect_uri = base_url('alumni/gcallback/');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("sbcur-g-login");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");

    $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); //<<-----This line shows error
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    $data['title']='';
    $data['meta_description']='';
    $data['meta_keywords']='';
    $data['section_name']='Alumni Dashboard';

    $this->load->view('templates/site_header',$data);//header
    $this->load->view('alumni_dashboard',$data);//content
    $this->load->view('templates/site_footer',$data);//footer
}
```

As indicated above, the authenticate() method in the gcallback() function shows error.
And the error message that is get is

```
GET http://localhost/sbcci/alumni/gcallback/?code=4/C4EKKTUlqGTbwFMwQq6xH2CTBF1bD68opeZexHWOl7M net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Please advice what's wrong i am doing.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong, For what I know, google-plus redirect_uri may not be localhost. Just check if it works on production server...

Comment: this is why I use https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client --> https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google

Comment: @qwertzman I don't think this is working for localhost redirects either!

Comment: guys pls help me to solve the above problem or at least point me to a tutorial based on CI v3.1.4

Comment: Wait .. doesn't this need to be encrypted with https? But yeah in order for this to work on localhost you're going to have to do some extra configuration. Test it on a domain.